# Bootstrap dropdown as context menu in Angular 4 application

Tags: angular, contextmenu, bootstrap-4

Is there a simple way how to toggle Bootstrap 4 dropdown menu on contextmenu event in Angular 4 application without using ngx-bootstrap library?

The Bootstrap documentation says that you can toggle the dropdown from JavaScript by calling:

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
```

So I tried to execute this in the contextmenu event handler but it did not work. I always get an error saying:

> ...dropdown is not a function

I have also tried to call *dropdown()* function directly on the native element of *ElementRef* got from *@ViewChild()* but I get the same error.

Where is the problem? I can toggle the dropdown by using data attributes (so I assume Bootstrap scripts work here) but it is not possible to toggle it on contextmenu this way, or is it?

I would prefer a solution without any external library.

Comment: Yes, I have them both loaded from CDN as Bootstrap documentation suggests.

Comment: I think it's much better to not mix jQuery with angular. Why don't you want to use `ngx-bootstrap`?

Comment: I said the same thing, jQuery and Angular will cause you display issues, do it using Angular only is so easy. Create a closedMenu and closedSubMenu (if you want accordion menu) and play with class decorator :)

Comment: I try to avoid using jQuery but it was in the example so I tried it. It does not work either when I try to execute `this.dropdownToggle.nativeElement['dropdown']()` where `dropdownToggle` is a template variable on the toggle element. This should be an equivalent to the jQuery call, or not?

Comment: I do not want to use `ngx-bootstrap` because it is just huge and I do not need most of the functionality it provides. But I have tried it and `BsDropdownDirective` just doesn't work either here. When I reference it through `@ViewChild(BsDropdownDirective)` the variable is `undefined` when I try to access it from contextmenu event handler. I have added an import to the core module of my application so I do not really now what is wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally realized that just showing the Bootstrap dropdown menu would not be enough and I would also like to position the context menu where I clicked but do not want to implement this by myself.

That is why I have decided to use [ngx-contextmenu](https://github.com/isaacplmann/ngx-contextmenu) although I previously mentioned that I did not want to use any external library. It is quite easy to set up and also makes use of Bootstrap dropdown styles which is what I wanted to accomplish in the first place.

If anybody wants to use this library, just be aware of [this bug](https://github.com/isaacplmann/ngx-contextmenu/issues/63) which cases that the context menu is not shown by default at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is maybe too complicated for toggle the dropdown, there is much easier :

Why don't you just add a [class.hidden]="menuClosed" like :

`<div [class.hidden]="menuClosed" class="dropdown">` ?

Simply set your menuClosed variable to true or false in a toggle function and it will do the job.

EDIT : The cool thing with Angular 2+ is that you can quickly reproduce jQuery/Javascript behavior by using this kind of display rules

Comment: Sure, but then I have to deal with styling, blur events, etc. which just clutters my component. Bootstrap provides nice and easy solution for a dropdown menu. I just do not get it why it is not possible to bind it to contextmenu event easily.

Comment: I understand, yes it is possible but jQuery should not be used in an Angular project, as I already faced strange component behaviors. But if you really need jQuery, then check first you have on each link (<a href>) data-toggle="dropdown" attribute, then you should be able to $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();  In this case the action of opening the menu is managed by jquery.
Make sure you have jquery and javascript lib imported in your scripts. 

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_dropdown_js&stacked=h

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call dropdown methods on the ElementRef.

You need to cast it to NgbDropdown in the ViewChild options (idk from which ngVersion this is supported...):

```
@ViewChild('ngbDropdownTemplateVarName', {read: NgbDropdown})
```

Then you can use it as a dropdown instead of an ElementRef, which only provides the HTML item.